# AWS lambda with IoT analytics pipeline batch message

Tags: c#, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

I have configured the IoT analytics pipeline with a lambda activity and set the batch size as 10, I wonder what the parameters are for the functionhandler method to receive batched message? I generated a sample c# code as below:

```
public string FunctionHandler(string input, ILambdaContext context)
```

but I would expect something like

```
public void FunctionHandler(event input, ILambdaContext context)
```

what exactly is the type for the first parameter?

Comment: I guess I find the answer myself, I simply create a class which contains all the property in the message, for example, Class MyMessage, then just set the first parameter as MyMessage[] input, that worked. also I need to decorate [LambdaSerializer(typeof(JsonSerializer))] on my FunctionHandler method